Is sentence itself a syntactic function or not?
There are syntactic functions of subordinate clauses. But what about main clauses?
For example:
Assertive clause: He is a good student.
Is its syntactic function sentence itself or something else?

No: no function is assigned to the clause itself because it is not part of any larger construction.

But in sentence with: main clause + subordinate clause. Should we call main clause complement?

No, because the main clause is not a complement of anything.

Yᴏᴜʀ Qᴜᴇꜱᴛɪᴏɴꜱ Aʀᴇ Tᴏᴏ Sʜᴏʀᴛ: please put more effort into composing your questions, as it is unfair to expect others to put more effort into answering than you have put into asking. Tell us what led you to ask the question, such as some confusion or lack of clarity over some particular theory or model, what you think the answer may be, or why you question there even being a clear answer. What research into this matter did you do and where, and what in particular did you find there that seems unclear or conflicting to you? What is your own guess or guesses, and why do you think so?

The misconception that consists in thinking that a sentence could have a syntactic function should be cleared away through a careful examination of what is a syntactic function and what is a sentence; the conclusion is that this would not make sense.

(CoGEL § 2.7) The grammatical hierarchy
[…]  units of grammar may be placed in a hierarchy of POTENTIAL SIZE or EXTENSIBILITY as follows:
HIGHEST UNIT: SENTENCES, which consist of one or more
                                CLAUSES, which consist of one or more
                                PHRASES, which consist of one or more
                                WORDS, which consist of one or more
LOWEST UNIT: MORPHEMES

"Sentence" is not a function, merely a unit or block, made out of other units.

Grammar Error syntactic function In linguistics, grammatical relations (also called grammatical functions, grammatical roles, or syntactic functions) are functional relationships between constituents in a clause.

Sentences are never a constituent in any unit, from which follows that they can't enter into a grammatical relation with another constituent. Also, syntactic functions (in other words, grammatical relations), as they are relations (binary), must involve two constituents, whereas at the level of the sentence there is not even one constituent to talk about.

In other words, a sentence is not a complement (or other function) of anything, as I said in comments.

@BillJ Not "in other words", but "as an immediate consequence".

You need to understand the meaning of the expression "in other words". It means 'to put it another way'.

@BillJ Here, again, you are wrong: I do understand that "in other words"  means "to put it another way"; what you need to understand is that "a sentence is not a complement (or other function) of anything" is derived from my explanation, that it is the effect following the cause I highlight. In a cause and effect relationship the effect can't be another way of explaining the cause, it can only be a consequence.

I'm not wrong. There's no 'cause and effect relationship'. The simple fact is that sentences have no function because they are not a complement of anything. And the same applies to main clauses. That's all that needed to be said.

@BillJ Let's leave it at that then, you are not wrong.
